# Invoke abstract class constructor only once and not in every specific class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have something like this:

```
public abstract class Handler {

    protected ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public Handler(ItemRepository itemRepository) {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
    }
}

public class SpecificHandler1 extends Handler {    

    public SpecificHandler1(ItemRepository itemRepository) {
        super(itemRepository);
    }
}

public class SpecificHandler2 extends Handler {    

    public SpecificHandler2(ItemRepository itemRepository) {
        super(itemRepository);
    }
}
```

I don't want to pass ItemRepository as an argument for each specific handler as it'll always be the same instance of itemRepository. I'd like to pass the ItemRepository only once. I'm not working with Spring boot which would make my life easier using @Autowired annotation. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What you have is the correct way. Another possible design would be for each of the methods to accept the item repository as a parameter, instead of storing it as a field, but this may not be a sensible design in your specific case.

Comment: If you mean that there is only one itemRepository for all Handler class instances (including all its derived class instances), then make it a static variable.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to pass ItemRepository as an argument for each specific
> handler as it'll always be the same instance of itemRepository.

While that is not DRY (don't repeat yourself), what you do is the correct way.
Dependencies of classes should ideally be set when the object is instantiated or when not suitable via a setter.
To achieve that the subclass has to declare the`itemRepository` as parameter of the constructor or at worst as setter.
With or without Spring Boot you would encounter the same "problem" (that is not a problem in fact).

A simple way to be DRY (among others) that I would not recommend would be to "hide"/strong couple the `itemRepository` dependency in the abstract class :

```
public abstract class Handler {

    protected ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public Handler() {
        this.itemRepository = new ItemRepository();
    }
}
```

But as a side effect, you get a class that becomes not unit testable since `itemRepository` is not a visible dependency.